# Javascript/jQuery Maths Logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexbox

I have written a script for a flexbox grid functionality, however I am having some issues with the maths calculations to find out how many items are on the last row as I wish to apply a class to them in order to fix flexbox styling in the case it's not a full row.

My situation:

I have 4 layouts: 1 Column, 2 Column, 3 Column and 4 Columns.

In different cases I would have the following situation:

1. For 4 Column layout there may be 3 remaining on the bottom row.
2. For 4 Column layout there may be 2 remaining on the bottom row.
3. For 4 Column layout there may be 1 remaining on the bottom row.
4. For 3 Column layout there may be 2 remaining on the bottom row.
5. For 3 Column layout there may be 1 remaining on the bottom row.
6. For 2 Column layout there may be 1 remaining on the bottom row.

In each of these circumstances I need to add different classes to the items remaining on the bottom row, these classes being:

1. flex-last (for the last/singular item left on a row)
2. flex-second-last (for the 2nd to last item on a row)
3. flex-third-last (for the 3rd to last item on a row)

These classes must only be applied if the row is not full e.g. if there is 4 items on the bottom row for 4 column, nothing should be applied as no styling fixes are required.

My current code was working fine however I have run into an instance where I have 43 items in the grid and the maths seems to have issues.

As the screensize gets smaller it corrects the layout to be smaller and smaller until its 1 column, this means that the calculations must work in all cases.

Below is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".flex-container").each(function() {
        var flexColumns = $(this).attr("rel");
        var self = $(this);

        function flexboxFixes(){
            if(self.find(".flex-item").hasClass("flex-cols-3")) {
                var flexItemCount = self.find('.flex-cols-3').length;
                if ((flexItemCount - 1) % 3 === 0) {
                    self.find(".flex-cols-3:last-of-type").addClass("flex-last");
                } else if ((flexItemCount - 1) % 3 !== 0 && flexItemCount % 3 !== 0 ) {
                    self.find(".flex-cols-3:last-of-type").addClass("flex-last");
                    self.find(".flex-cols-3:nth-last-of-type(2)").addClass("flex-second-last");
                }   
            } else if(self.find(".flex-item").hasClass("flex-cols-4")) {
                var flexItemCount = self.find('.flex-cols-4').length;
                if ((flexItemCount - 1) % 4 === 0) {
                    self.find(".flex-cols-4:last-of-type").addClass("flex-last");
                } else if ((flexItemCount - 2) % 4 === 0) {
                    self.find(".flex-cols-4:last-of-type").addClass("flex-last");
                    self.find(".flex-cols-4:nth-last-of-type(2)").addClass("flex-second-last");
                } else if ((flexItemCount - 2) % 4 !== 0 && flexItemCount % 4 !== 0) {
                    self.find(".flex-cols-4:last-of-type").addClass("flex-last");
                    self.find(".flex-cols-4:nth-last-of-type(2)").addClass("flex-second-last");
                    self.find(".flex-cols-4:nth-last-of-type(3)").addClass("flex-third-last");
                }   
            } else if(self.find(".flex-item").hasClass("flex-cols-2")) {
                var flexItemCount = self.find('.flex-cols-2').length;
                if ((flexItemCount - 1) % 2 === 0) { //Is there 1 extra?
                    self.find(".flex-cols-2:last-of-type").addClass("flex-last");
                }
            }
        }
        flexboxFixes();

        $(window).bind('resize',function(){flexboxFixes();});
    });
});
```

**Notes worth noting:**

These might help you figure out how we can do the maths without conflict?

1. X / 1 Always Equals whole number
2. X / 2 Always Equals whole number or .5
3. X / 3 Always Equals whole number or .33 or .66
4. X / 4 Always Equals whole number or .25 or .5 or .75
5. Whole Number never Decimal = full row
6. 2 col, .5 = 1 left over
7. 3 col, .33 = 1 left over, .66 = 2 left over
8. 4 col, .25 = 1 left over, .5 = 2 left over, .75 = 3 left over

I am thinking something along the lines of first checking the layout, then checking the decimal values to see how many items remain as this will be the same across all numbers?

```
var flexItemCount = self.find('.flex-cols-4').length;
var flexItemMath = flexItemCount / 4;
alert(flexItemMath % 1);

if (flexItemMath % columnCount) == 0.X
```

would this seem feasible?

Comment: what exactly is happening, when you have 43 elements?

Comment: with 43 elements in a 4 col layout it does not add "flex-last" to the last element instead it adds  "flex-second-last" the item prior it adds "flex-third-last" leaving the actual 3rd last without a class causing styles to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After previously overthinking the whole think I discovered a simple answer, the answer checks the decimal value for the certain column layout when divided by amount of columns.

```
if(self.find(".flex-item").hasClass("flex-cols-3")) {
    var flexItemCount = self.find('.flex-cols-3').length;
    var flexItemMath = flexItemCount / 3; //NEW
    flexItemMath = flexItemMath % 1; //NEW

    var flexItemRound = Number(flexItemMath).toFixed(2); //NEW

    if (flexItemRound == 0.00) { //NEW

    } else if (flexItemRound == 0.33) { //NEW
        self.find(".flex-cols-3:last-of-type").addClass("flex-last");//1 remainder 0.33
    } else if (flexItemRound == 0.66) { //NEW
        self.find(".flex-cols-3:last-of-type").addClass("flex-last");
        self.find(".flex-cols-3:nth-last-of-type(2)").addClass("flex-second-last"); //2 remainder 0.66
    }   
}
```